# Unable to play encrypted video in iframe in chrome. Firefox and edge can play the same iframes with the same URL

Tags: c#, google-chrome, wix, azure-media-services, azure-media-player

We are creating a video hosting site using azure. Since the videos we intend to propagate are private mixed with public, we have decided to use encryption(Widevine and Playready) and a log in system. Since we also have public videos, we provided users to create an embed URL for the videos. We a We facilitated this using a document id and a view that is publicly accessible and this view will be in the embed URL. When a request with the valid document id reaches this view, we call another view with the credentials for decrypting that video. In this view the video is played using azure media player. All this is working in most sites but for some sites especially websites created using Wix,Strikingly 
 and Godaddy , it shows the below error:

**Encrypted Media access has been blocked because of a Feature Policy applied to the current document. See [this link](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-permissions-in-cross-origin-iframes) for more details.**

I have already added the allow="encrypted-media" permission in the embed code, but of no use.

I am also getting this error code - error: videojs: 2.2.4.1 (CODE:273678337 undefined)  [object Object]

Has anyone run in to a similar situation and found a solution for the same? If so please do help.

Comment: Did you solve this issue - if not are you able to share an example link?

Comment: We expect it was an issue with the site where we embedded the video. Check this link - https://www.wix.com/corvid/forum/community-discussion/unable-to-play-azure-encrypted-video-in-iframe-in-chrome-firefox-and-edge-can-play-the-same .Even after noticing the wix admins about the issue they have not even responded. Hence we are not using wix anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome didn't acknowledge the iFrame allow attribute for me until I included an allow list after 'encrypted-media' so try adding a wildcard * to the attribute like so:

```
<iframe allow="encrypted-media *;" src="..."></iframe>
```

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks.